# Combine feature collection into polygon turfjs

Tags: geojson, turfjs

I'm trying to find out if a point lies within my country boundary.  I'm using this data set as my country boundary: http://eric.clst.org/wupl/Stuff/gz_2010_us_outline_5m.json

And currently I'm check this point [-97.5164,35.4676]

```
function(){

    var pt = turf.point(origin);
    return turf.inside(pt, gz_2010_us_outline_5m);
}
```

How do I setup my geojson boundary data with turfjs so that it can be combined into a polygon to check if the point falls inside?

Answer (score 1):

Just use turfs http://turfjs.org/docs/#lineToPolygon which Converts (Multi)LineString(s) to Polygon(s).

Comment: Thanks for noting. They changed their site

Comment: can you check here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55974083/attempting-to-a-configurable-attribute-of-a-configurable-property-issue-in-turfj