# Attempting to a configurable attribute of a configurable property Issue-in turfJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, geojson, turfjs

I have an issue with **@turf/turf** the last version, in my react native app

> "react-native": "0.58.0",
>
> "@turf/turf": "^5.1.6"

I just followed the same example in the README.md but it's not working with me anymore.

The issue is when I import turf like this

```
import * as turf from '@turf/turf';
```

and write the function here is

```
handleNearby = () => {
        const { region, providers } = this.state;
        let currentPoint = [region.longitude, region.latitude]
        let points = _.map(providers, p => {
            console.log('@p', p);
            const to = [p.coordinates.longitude, p.coordinates.latitude];
            const distance = turf.distance(currentPoint, to, { units: 'kilometers' });
            return { coords: p.coordinates, name: p.username, id: p.id, distance }
        });
        const sortPoints = _.sortBy(points, ['distance']);
        this.setState({ sortedMarkers: sortPoints });
        console.log('@#points', sortPoints);
        return;
        
    }
```

and run the app I have this error

```
  attempting to a configurable attribute of a configurable property
```

[image: Error]

But when I run the debugger on the browser the app works well I don't know why! any help?

Comment: You don't show the full stack trace. Can you look through it and see it if mentions one of your source files?

Comment: Also are you aware of what it means for a property of an object to be configurable or not?

Comment: @MatthiasDailey Really I don't know what that means! , you want to see other Code in my app or what?

Comment: In your picture, it shows a list where each item has a function name and a file path (and line number and character). The list is cut off, so I can't see the whole list. Can you paste the full list? Or search through it yourself --- All of the file paths I can see are files in your `khadamati_app`'s  node_modules folder. But somewhere in the list there is one of _your_ source files. Can you find it and paste that line?

Comment: For the configurable part, here's an article: http://arqex.com/967/javascript-properties-enumerable-writable-configurable

Comment: But all of this in node_modules **Turfjs** lib I can't edit or manipulation of them but in the whole list I found two lines refer to my files, `<unknown> mapScreen.js: 4` here is that line " import * as turf from '@turf/turf'; " and the second line is `App.js:2` " import MyApp from './src/navigations/Route'; "

Comment: I see, then it looks like the problem is in turf.js, probably behaving badly in the React Native environment. Are you able to ignore the error?

Comment: Maybe yes when i Run the debugger the error disappear!! But i don't know what happens when publishing the app !!

Comment: I don't know either