# Cant correctly rotate point using GeoPandas

Tags: python, rotation, geo, geopandas, turfjs

My Python code:

```
from geopandas import GeoSeries
from shapely.geometry import Point

WGS84 = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
p1 = (41.8121843, 45.2178516,)
p2 = (41.8124878, 45.2177536,)

point2 = Point(p2)

s2 = GeoSeries(point2, crs=WGS84)
rotated = s2.rotate(90, p1)  # Try to rotate p2 around p1

print(rotated)  # 41.8122823 45.2181551
```

My JS code (Turf.js):

```
var p1 = [41.8121843, 45.2178516];
var p2 = [41.8124878, 45.2177536];

var l = turf.lineString( [p1, p2] );
L.geoJson(l, {style: {color: '#0000ff', fillOpacity: 1, fillColor: '#0000ff', opacity: 1}}).addTo(map);

// Rotate line around p1
var trufRotated = turf.transformRotate(l, -90, {pivot: p1});
L.geoJson(trufRotated, {style: {color: '#ff0000'}}).addTo(map);
```

Illustration. Blue is original line. Red is line rotated using Turf.js (ok). Green is line rotated using GeoPandas (not ok):

[image]

Green line rotated using geopandas have wrong offset. Maybe it is problem of projection but I cant figure out how to fix it.

My question is how to rotate correctly using GeoPandas?

Comment: geopandas dispatches its *geometric* operations to shapely. I wouldn't expect operations like this work in geographic coordinates. Reproject to a local coordinate system.

Comment: @PaulH I tryed to use `rotated = rotated.to_crs(WGS84)` after rotation but it has no positive effect. May you show example how to do it correctly?

Comment: you need to project *before* the rotation

Comment: @PualH can you check here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55974083/attempting-to-a-configurable-attribute-of-a-configurable-property-issue-in-turfj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Thanks to @PaulH. I need to make rotation in Mercator and translate it again in lon/lat:

```
WGS84 = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
MERC = {'init': 'epsg:3857'}

p1 = (41.8121843, 45.2178516,)
p2 = (41.8124878, 45.2177536,)

point1 = Point(p1)
point2 = Point(p2)

s1 = GeoSeries(point1, crs=WGS84)
s2 = GeoSeries(point2, crs=WGS84)

s11 = s1.to_crs(MERC)
s22 = s2.to_crs(MERC)

rotated = s22.rotate(90, s11[0])
rotated = rotated.to_crs(WGS84)
print(rotated)
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, this did not work for me. geopandas.rotate() simply does not want to cooperate with my shapefile! If anyone else is experiencing similar issues, a dirty way to achieve the same thing is

```
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely.geometry as geom
import random

# Generate geodataframe with random coordinates
geo = [geom.Point(random.uniform(-180, 180), random.uniform(-90, 90)) for _ in range(10)]
points = points.GeoDataFrame(geometry=geo)

def rotate_points(point):
    x,y = point
    return(y,-x)

gdf['geometry'] = gdf['geometry'].apply(lambda geom: geom.coords[0]).apply(rotate_points).apply(Point)
```

This will rotate all points 90 degrees clockwise relative to the origin. Of course, this can be generalized to any other rotations, the simplest being integers of 90, by replacing

```
return(y,-x)
```

with the appropriate transformation.

For 90 degrees counterclockwise:

```
return(-y,x)
```

For 180 degrees:

```
return(-x,-y)
```